MAUI app crashes when some DX controls initialize
I'm using DevExpress components in my MAUI app and someone who is helping me test it says the app crashes whenever they open some specific page.
From the app's logs I can see the problem is with some components when they are initialized but have no idea what exactly is wrong as everything works fine on two of my Android devices.

Method
MyApp.MobileAppLogic.ViewModels.DocListViewModel.set_GridFilter(string)' is inaccessible from method MyApp.Views.DocListPage.typedBindingsM__277(MyApp.MobileAppLogic.ViewModels.DocListViewModel,string)'

What am I missing here?

Issues like this sometimes arise on iOS after updating .NET/MAUI and running the app without first cleaning the bin/obj folders. This happens because the linker doesn’t always rebuild the entire solution after a .NET update, resulting in parts of the application being built with different versions.
However, I’m not sure if this applies to your specific situation. If the exception is still raised, you can create a ticket on DevExpress Support Center: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/create

The problem happens on Android. Thank you for the support link.
